# Deploying v2 cloud functions 'unable to resolve path to module ...'

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, eslint

It appears to be in a vicious cycle.

Whenever I import  `onDocumentUpdated` trigger like this:
`import { onDocumentUpdated } from 'firebase-functions/v2/firestore';`

`yarn lint` throws the following error, therefore I can't deploy:

```
/XXX/functions/src/notifications/sendNotification.ts
  2:35  error  Unable to resolve path to module 'firebase-functions/v2/firestore'  import/no-unresolved

✖ 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)
```

Whenever I import the function like this:
`import { onDocumentUpdated } from 'firebase-functions/lib/v2/providers/firestore';`

linter passes but then `firebase deploy` throws this error:

```
Error [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]: Package subpath './lib/v2' is not defined by "exports" in /XXX/functions/node_modules/firebase-functions/package.json
    at exportsNotFound (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:303:10)
    at packageExportsResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:650:9)
    at resolveExports (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:591:36)
    at Module._findPath (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:668:31)
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1130:27)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:985:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1235:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:176:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/XXX/functions/lib/index.js:28:14)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1376:14) {
  code: 'ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED'
}


Error: Functions codebase could not be analyzed successfully. It may have a syntax or runtime error
```

The second error makes sense. When I look at the `package.json` of `firebase-functions` then the exports look like following:

```
      "v2": [
        "lib/v2"
      ],
      "v2/core": [
        "lib/v2/core"
      ],
      "v2/alerts": [
        "lib/v2/providers/alerts"
      ],
      "v2/alerts/appDistribution": [
        "lib/v2/providers/alerts/appDistribution"
      ],
      "v2/alerts/billing": [
        "lib/v2/providers/alerts/billing"
      ],
      "v2/alerts/crashlytics": [
        "lib/v2/providers/alerts/crashlytics"
      ],
      "v2/alerts/performance": [
        "lib/v2/providers/alerts/performance"
      ],
      "v2/base": [
        "lib/v2/base"
      ],
      "v2/database": [
        "lib/v2/providers/database"
      ],
      "v2/eventarc": [
        "lib/v2/providers/eventarc"
      ],
      "v2/identity": [
        "lib/v2/providers/identity"
      ],
      "v2/options": [
        "lib/v2/options"
      ],
      "v2/https": [
        "lib/v2/providers/https"
      ],
      "v2/pubsub": [
        "lib/v2/providers/pubsub"
      ],
      "v2/storage": [
        "lib/v2/providers/storage"
      ],
      "v2/tasks": [
        "lib/v2/providers/tasks"
      ],
      "v2/scheduler": [
        "lib/v2/providers/scheduler"
      ],
      "v2/remoteConfig": [
        "lib/v2/providers/remoteConfig"
      ],
      "v2/testLab": [
        "lib/v2/providers/testLab"
      ],
      "v2/firestore": [
        "lib/v2/providers/firestore"
      ]
    }
  },
```

Why is the linter not be able resolve the path? The paths are already properly exported :/

Comment: You should probably show the configuration for your entire project (a complete minimal reproducible example). Anyone should be able to reproduce the problem using the instructions you provide.  This includes things like package.json, TypeScript config, and lint config.